# How can I extract List items using XPath without pulling in navigation?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, extract

I am using a 3rd party scraper/crawler tool to pull in data from pages across a range of domains.

For example: Loading in the top 10 ranked articles for keyword 'x' and then pulling back elements of each page using some x path functions.

There are a couple of new elements I would like to start pulling, but I am not sure what the best approach would be to bring back the most accurate results.

Objectives:

1. Pull back the counts of ul, ol and li items across an article set
2. Pull back the text in each list element to compare how publishers
   are writing on key topics

The issue is that I don't want to pull back navigation / menu elements that contain list items.  I only want to pull in the data inside the body of each written article.

The easiest way might be to look for the H1 tag (since most sites only have 1 and its the main title of an article... and then pull the list items that show up AFTER the h1 tag.   This should in theory eliminate anything in the main nav... but I am not sure how to do that in XPath.

Any idea on what the best approach might be to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, XPath expressions with correct predicates and axes methods should work. Do you get pages from multiple websites or just only one ? The latter, the easiest. Feel free to provide a sample of data.

Comment: We do both depending on the project.   For this purpose we are actually looking to pull elements out for a series of high ranking pages across a range of domains.  However, we do often run this type of deep dive on individual sites as well for audits.